# Send Raw TCP + IPV4 Packet Did not Work. Different Output from Wireshark

Tags: c, sockets

I have a Programm which sends TCP/Ipv4 Packet to my Localhost adress.

I try to expand my Programm so i edit / set the Ip Flags in the Ip Header. After I do that and start the Programm i only receive  in Wireshark a packet with ipv4 Protocol, so it did not send the tcp packet with the Ip packet.

The Programm is work if i used my old Ip Header, so without the Ip Flags.

Did you know, why the program did not send ipv4+tcp packet?

---

## Maybe you will understand my Problem, if you look at my Headers and Output from Wireshark for each Input below.

---

My Old Ip Header:

```
struct ipheader {
    unsigned char ip_hl :4, ip_v :4;
    unsigned char ip_tos;
    unsigned short int ip_len;
    unsigned short int ip_id;
    unsigned short int ip_off;

    unsigned char ip_ttl;
    unsigned char ip_p;
    unsigned short int ip_sum;
    unsigned int ip_src;
    unsigned int ip_dst;
};
```

My Old Tcp Header:

```
struct tcpheader {
    unsigned short int th_sport;
    unsigned short int th_dport;
    unsigned int th_seq;
    unsigned int th_acknum;
    unsigned char th_reserved :4, th_off :4;
    unsigned int th_fin :1, th_syn :1, th_rst :1, th_psh :1, th_ack :1,
            th_urg :1, th_cwr :1, th_ece :1, th_ns :1;
    unsigned short int th_win;
    unsigned short int th_sum;
    unsigned short int th_urp;
};
```

---

My New IP Header

```
struct ipheader {
    unsigned char ip_hl :4, ip_v :4;
    unsigned char ip_tos:8;
    unsigned short int ip_len:16;
    unsigned short int ip_id:16;

    unsigned short int ip_moreFrag:1,
         ip_doNotFrag :1, ip_reserved :1;


    unsigned short int ip_off:13;


    unsigned char ip_ttl:8;
    unsigned char ip_p:8;
    unsigned short int ip_sum:16;
    unsigned int ip_src:32;
    unsigned int ip_dst:32;
};
```

My NEW TCP - Header:

```
struct tcpheader {
    unsigned short int th_sport:16;
    unsigned short int th_dport:16;
    unsigned int th_seq:32;
    unsigned int th_acknum:32;
    unsigned char th_reserved :4, th_off :4;
//  unsigned char th_flags;
//  unsigned int tcp_res1 :4, th_hlen :4;
    unsigned int th_fin :1, th_syn :1, th_rst :1, th_psh :1, th_ack :1,
            th_urg :1, th_cwr :1, th_ece :1; //th_ns :1;
    unsigned short int th_win:16;
    unsigned short int th_sum:16;
    unsigned short int th_urp:16;
};
```

---

First Input:

```
   "ip_v": "4",
      "ip_hl": "5" ,

      "ip_type": "16" ,
      "ip_off": "0",


      "ip_reserved" : "0",
      "ip_DoNotFragment": "1",
      "ip_MoreFragment": "1",



      "ip_len": "200",
      "ip_id": "4321",

      "ip_ttl": "255",
      "ip_proto": "6",
     
      "ip_sum": "0", 
      "ip_src": "1.2.3.4",
      "ip_dest":"127.0.0.1",
      "ip_data": "------" ,

      "tcp_sourcePort": "1000", 
      "tcp_destPort": "1000",

      "tcp_seqnum" : "0",
      "tcp_acknum" : "0",

      "tcp_reserved" : "4",
      "tcp_offset" : "5",


      "tcp_fin" : "0",
      "tcp_syn" : "1",
      "tcp_rst" : "0",
      "tcp_psh" : "0",
      "tcp_ack" : "1",
      "tcp_urg" : "0",


      "tcp_cwr" : "1",
      "tcp_ece" : "1",
    

      "tcp_win" : "32767",
      "tcp_sum": "0", 
      "tcp_urp" : "0"
```

---

Second Imput is the same. The different between first and the second Input is that i set for the ip flags a value of 0 instead of 1

So if I use the First input i get in Wireshark somethink like this:

[Output Wireshark for First Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc5Ig.png)

---

If i use the Second Input, so for all Ip Flags the value 0, i get in Wireshark this output:

[Output Wireshark for Second Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j8S9.png)

---

## SOURCE Code for Programm

```
// Run as root or SUID 0,

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

// Packet length
#define PCKT_LEN 8192

struct ipheader {
    unsigned char ip_hl :4, ip_v :4;
    unsigned char ip_tos :8;
    unsigned short int ip_len :16;
    unsigned short int ip_id :16;
    unsigned short int ip_off :13;

    unsigned short int ip_moreFrag :1, ip_doNotFrag:1, ip_reserved : 1;

    unsigned char ip_ttl :8;
    unsigned char ip_p :8;
    unsigned short int ip_sum :16;
    unsigned int iph_sourceip :32;
    unsigned int iph_destip :32;
};


/* Structure of a TCP header */
struct tcpheader {
    unsigned short int th_sport :16;
    unsigned short int th_dport :16;
    unsigned int th_seq :32;
    unsigned int th_acknum :32;
    unsigned char th_reserved :4, th_off :4;


    unsigned short int th_fin :1, th_syn :1, th_rst :1, th_psh :1, th_ack :1,
            th_urg :1, th_cwr :1, th_ece :1;


    unsigned short int th_win :16;
    unsigned short int th_sum :16;
    unsigned short int th_urp :16;
};


unsigned short csum(unsigned short *buf, int len) {
    unsigned long sum;
    for (sum = 0; len > 0; len--)
        sum += *buf++;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    return (unsigned short) (~sum);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sd;

    // No data, just datagram
    char buffer[PCKT_LEN];

    // The size of the headers
    struct ipheader *ip = (struct ipheader *) buffer;
    struct tcpheader *tcp = (struct tcpheader *) (buffer
            + sizeof(struct ipheader));
    struct sockaddr_in sin, din;

    int one = 1;
    const int *val = &one;
    memset(buffer, 0, PCKT_LEN);

    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
    if (sd < 0) {
        perror("socket() error");
        exit(-1);
    } else
        printf("socket()-SOCK_RAW and tcp protocol is OK.\n");

    // The source is redundant, may be used later if needed
    // Address family
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    din.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // Source port, can be any, modify as needed
    sin.sin_port = htons(atoi("1000"));
    din.sin_port = htons(atoi("1000"));

    // Source IP, can be any, modify as needed
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");
    din.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    // IP structure
    ip->ip_v = 4;
    ip->ip_hl = 5;

    ip->ip_tos = 16;
    ip->ip_off = 0;

    ip->ip_reserved = 1;
    ip->ip_doNotFrag = 1;
    ip->ip_moreFrag = 1;

    ip->ip_len = htons(sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct tcpheader));
    ip->ip_id = htons(54321);
    ip->ip_ttl = 255;
    ip->ip_p = 6; // TCP
    ip->ip_sum = 0; // Done by kernel

    ip->iph_sourceip = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");

    ip->iph_destip = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    tcp->th_sport = htons(atoi("1000"));

    tcp->th_dport = htons(atoi("1000"));
    tcp->th_seq = htonl(0);
    tcp->th_acknum = 0;
    tcp->th_reserved = 4;
    tcp->th_off = 5;


    tcp->th_fin = 1;

    tcp->th_syn = 1;
    tcp->th_rst = 1;
    tcp->th_psh = 1;
    tcp->th_ack = 1;
    tcp->th_urg = 1;
    tcp->th_cwr = 1;

    tcp->th_ece = 1;

    tcp->th_win = htons(32767);
    tcp->th_sum = 0; // Done by kernel
    tcp->th_urp = 0;

    // IP checksum calculation
    ip->ip_sum = htons(
            csum((unsigned short *) buffer,
                    (sizeof(struct ipheader) + sizeof(struct tcpheader))));

    // Inform the kernel do not fill up the headers' structure, we fabricated our own
    if (setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt() error");
        exit(-1);
    } else
        printf("setsockopt() is OK\n");

    unsigned int count;

    if (sendto(sd, buffer, ip->ip_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &din, sizeof(din))
            < 0)
            // Verify
            {
        perror("sendto() error");
        exit(-1);
    } else
        printf("Count #%u - sendto() is OK\n", count);

    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your "new" IP header is not using bitfields correctly for the new flag fields you added.  The `ip_off` field needs to be 13 bits instead of 5 bits, and you should be using `unsigned short int` instead of `unsigned int` for the 3 flag fields, to match `ip_off`. Also, the placement of bits is not guaranteed across platforms so you may have an endian issue to deal with, too.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau it helps a little... next Problem is that, if i set the Ip flags, so Reserved bit, Dont fragment , Morefragment flags and send it to my localhost, and catch it with wireshark i see that the protocol is a Ipv4, but it should be TCP with all TCP headers. In wireshark it says protocol TCP (6) but it dont show me the header. While i dont set the ip flags, so i use a value of 0, wireshark shows me the Packet with all data i used.

Actually if i set the flags to 1, the flags did not change, so it told "not set", only the Fragment offset changed if i set the ipflags.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i wasn able to mention your name :D so i did it here ^

Comment: That still should like you are not setting up the bits correctly. For instance, if you have endian backwards. Also, please show your actual code for creating and sending the packets. Looking at your header definitions alone is really not enough to diagnose your problems.

Comment: @RemyLebeau got it, i edited my post again. This ist just for TCP and IP, later i will, if i am earn the experience why the Packet is not send correctly, write a same programm which sends UDP + IP and IICMP + IP

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did not know what i did wrong.. I actually control the header again.. but i did not found the problem.... Have you any information for me?